# Difference between null pointers and uninitialized pointers?

Tags: c++

Why can you print the value of a null pointer but not an uninitialized pointer? I mean when initializing a pointer to nullptr, you just explicitly make the pointer point to nowhere, right? If so, isn't that just the same as not initializing it, or is there something that I have missed?

Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: Imagine your small daughter walking by busy road. Do you think it's the same whether you tell her not to move anywhere as it is to not tell here anything at all?

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: "_initializing_ a pointer to _nullptr_, you just _explicitly_ make it point to _nowhere_". So, you're initializing it _with a known value_ and doing this _on purpose_, but still somehow making it point to nowhere... An uninitialized pointer can't even point to nowhere, it always has some random ("garbage") value that can be treated as some memory address.

Comment: @ForceBru: No, the original statement is accurate. A pointer with `nullptr` value indeed "points to nowhere", and doesn't have any "random" or "garbage" value whatsoever. Those pointers that _do_ have "random" or "garbage" values are actually indeterminate, and _cannot_ be treated as _any_ memory address.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, oops, I was actually talking about uninitialized pointers in the last sentence, gonna edit this ASAP

Comment: @ForceBru: I still stand by what I said

Comment: the nullptr keyword represents a null pointer value and tells the compiler that the pointer does not point to an object.  any pointer that is not initialized has an indeterminate value yet to be determined.  Possible point of confusion is where a hanging pointer may point...anywhere and nowhere.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition it is impossible for any variable to point to nowhere or contain nothing. The OS assigns each variable a location in ram and by virtue of it being ram means that the location '0x1111111' or wherever has and retains an old value or garbage value. Every bit in ram is either 0 or 1 which both represent a value. So an uninitialized variable or pointer will contain garbage or random values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pointing to nowhere, and being uninitialised, are two different concepts.

Strictly, an uninitialised pointer has an *indeterminate* value. It's not a pointer to the specific place "nowhere", or to an object. It's just … "shrug". You can't do anything with it yet.

*"The specific place 'nowhere'??"* I hear you ask. *"What is this nonsense?"* Well, quite. It's not really "nowhere". A null pointer has a specific value and a specific representation. It doesn't point to an object, but it is still a single, predictable, known value, reserved for this use.

**Valid pointer:** I'm at Kerrek's house, or at work, or at the pub, etc.
**Invalidated pointer:** I was at Kerrek's house, but Vlad from Moscow blew it up :( I'm currently watching the flames and crying a little.
**Null pointer:** I'm asleep at home. Come back in the morning, please.
**Uninitialised pointer:** I am very drunk and have no earthly idea where I am, if I'm even still alive.

Comment: I will need to be watching Vlad.

Comment: Thanks! But what can I say instead of "nowhere" then?

Comment: @Hei: "nowhere" will be fine; that's the colloquial terminology many of us use. I just wanted to explain that the technical reality doesn't really match the English language implication. That seemed to be the cornerstone of your confusion. Of course it _is_ true to say that a null pointer doesn't point anywhere, but that is also true of uninitialised pointers, so we need to say more about them, in order to understand.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition it is impossible for any variable to point to nowhere or contain nothing. The Operating System assigns each variable a location in ram and by virtue of it being ram means that the location '0x1111111' or wherever has and retains an old value or garbage value. Every bit in ram is either 0 or 1 which both represent a value. So an uninitialized variable or pointer will contain garbage or random values. If you adjudicate this reasoning further, knowing that all a pointer really is is a number of an index in ram, then you might say an uninitialized pointer points somewhere, hmm?

Comment: @KeithBecker Your entire comment is set at the wrong level of abstraction. _"knowing that all a pointer really is is a number of an index in ram"_ No. _"you might say an uninitialized pointer points somewhere, hmm?"_ No. Its value is indeterminate, a state which is indistinguishable from having no value at all. _"Every bit in ram is either 0 or 1 which both represent a value."_ RAM has absolutely nothing to do with this. We are not toggling bits on a CPU; we are programming in a high-level computer programming language.

Comment: Yes, we are talking on two different levels. I was answering the question as it relates to the machine. You were answering the question as it relates to the programmer; a very high level programmer, one that doesn't need to concern themselves with how a computer works. And yes number indexing in ram is how pointers work. Look it up.

Comment: @KeithBecker: This question is about C++, not about machine code. I don't need to "look it up", because (a) I know all that quite well already, thank you, and (b) it is utterly irrelevant. You on the other hand would do well to brush up on the purpose, meaning, rules and implementation of the programming language known as C++.

Comment: Respectfully, I only disagreed with the precept of your statement, "A pointer with nullptr value indeed 'points to nowhere', and doesn't have any 'random' or 'garbage' value whatsoever.", other than that, I don't think either of us should guess on each others knowledge of c++. I mean, unless you make it a habit of guessing. But we both really agree so, and I don't mean to argue at all. So I should apologize for that.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer (of type `T`) is a value, similar to other values like integers or strings, and it can be in one of three states:

1. It can point to an object or one past an object (and the two are not exclusive), or it points at a function. Such a pointer may be dereferenced if it points at an object or a function.
2. It can have the special value "null", in which case it compares equal to `T()` and to `nullptr` and to other expressions like `0`, `NULL`, `T(0)` and `T(nullptr)`.
3. It can be none of the above. This is true of the value of an uninitialized variable of type `T`, but never of a prvalue of `T`. This is also true if the pointer once did point to an object but the object's lifetime has ended.

Note that only case (2), the null pointer, is something that you can check for programmatically! You cannot in general tell whether a non-null pointer is valid (short of perhaps comparing a pointer to a set of known, valid pointers).

Comment: Thanks man! It makes a whole lot more sense. Why can't you select multiple answers.. I mean almost all of you came up with a great answer to my question so it is kinda hard to choose.

Comment: @Hei: Don't worry about it. Just select whatever *you* find helpful.

Comment: @Hei: General rule of thumb is to always accept _my_ answer, because my army is the largest and I know where all the uranium is kept. (Originally this was just in case Vlad tries to burn down my house, but things kind of ... spiralled out of control a bit)

Comment: @Hei: And BoundaryImplosion also needs the reputation to afford his/her next screen name change...

Comment: Yes, that's also true. Identify theft is not as cheap as it looks on the telly.

Comment: That's sounds logical.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean when initializing a pointer to nullptr, you just explicitly make the pointer point to nowhere, right? If so, isn't that just the same as not initializing it.

No both are not same!

**Reference: C++ Primer**

The value (i.e., the address) stored in a pointer can be in one of four states:

1. It can point to an object.
2. It can point to the location just immediately past the end of an object.
3. It can be a null pointer, indicating that it is not bound to any object.
4. It can be invalid; values other than the preceding three are invalid.

When we say a pointer is initialized to `nullptr` it means the pointer is not bound to any object.

An uninitialized pointer is in the invalid state (point 4 above).

You can check if a pointer is null, however dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined and may result in a run-time crash.

Comment: An uninitialized pointer doesn't "point to a garbage value". It *is* a garbage value. And a null pointer does not "point to `nullptr`".

Comment: This imagined performance cost would be interesting to measure. Performance cost compared to what? Not having the pointer at all? Well, obviously!

Comment: Pointers are used to hold the address of a variable so it points to a garbage value is more correct sir.

Comment: No, sir, it isn't.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Why it is not? What is the difference between your `indeterminate` value and garbage value?

Comment: @user1336087: You said it points to a garbage value. It does not. It does not point anywhere, because it _has_ a garbage value. Kerrek already said that and you disputed it, so I fear we'll be going around in circles.

Comment: @user1336087: A null pointer does not point to anything. Only certain values of pointers point to something, and null pointers are not among them (see my answer). In other words, pointing to something is a value-dependent privilege, not a right.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thank you for explaining it to me. But still, it amazes me that a null pointer doesn't point to `0` according to you? Could you please let me know where can I read about this officially?

Comment: You need to grok that C++ is an _abstraction_. A concept. Your C++ source code isn't a one-to-one mapping of instructions that will be executed by a CPU. It's a _description_ of how a program should behave. In the language we use to describe our programs, a null pointer simply is this way.

Comment: @user1336087: That's tough, it's implied by omission. There's no "official document" that lists all things that aren't true. There is however a document that says which pointers values represent the location of objects, and the null pointer is not of that kind.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing a null pointer"? You can read a null pointer value, but you cannot dereference it, just like you cannot dereference invalid pointers and past-the-end pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Made it clear. You are right one should not dereference null pointers one should check if it is `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

`nullptr` means nowhere, that's OK! and is a good practice initialize pointers to this defined value.
But being uninitialized it can point Anywhere, it is undefined and can lead to undefined behavior

Comment: Okay great, thank you! But when you say "But being uninitialized it can point Anywhere", you say that it is actually pointing to somewhere - So why can't I print the value? Nevertheless, it should at least be 0 right?

Comment: @Hei You can print the value of the pointer(That is an address), but you can't derreferenciate it, to print the value that is pointed because it can lead to UB, for example this could be an invalid or resticted address. Not only 0 it could be any number than can be reprented in that pointer

Comment: @Rama: _"You can print the value of the pointer(That is an address)"_ Actually, no, you can't. That's a common misconception. It might look like you can do it ("it's just an address!"), but actually your program will have undefined behaviour long before you even attempt a dereference.

Comment: @Hei: _"you say that it is actually pointing to somewhere - So why can't I print the value?"_ It's a conceptual thing. The standard says that we are not allowed to, because the value is _indeterminate_. Due to the nature of our physical reality, you could extract a physical value for it from your computer, but you'd be violating the rules of C++, which is an _abstraction_.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, Hei, So you can violate the Rules, Only for fun, but don't do that in production please!

Comment: Indeed. Ideally, not at all, but I can't control that :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, so if the standard says that you are not allowed to access the value(if this is how to word it), why is it even allowed to leave a pointer uninitialized?

Comment: @Hei: You are not forced to access it before later assigning a meaningful value. `int* ptr; /* ... */ ptr = nullptr;` Why prohibit this?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, hmm yeah it actually makes sense when you set it up like that. But isn't there a rule or something for this or is it just general logic?

Comment: @Hei: If you're asking why `int* ptr;` is allowed, this is called "default-initialisation" and it is defined as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: Forgot to update the page. Thanks! That was what I meant :)

Answer (score 2):

In some languages like C# and Java an uninitialized pointer contains NULL.

On the other hand, C++ follows the philosophy of not wasting any clock cycles doing things which you have not explicitly asked it to, (how successful the language is at that is a different story,) so C++ does not waste any time initializing pointers to NULL, so in C++ an uninitialized pointer is said to contain garbage.

The problem with garbage is that later you cannot say `if( pointer == garbage ) { pointer = someMeaningfulValue; }` because you do not know what the garbage value is so as to compare against it.  You cannot reproduce it.

So, by saying `pointer = NULL;` you have initialized the pointer with a value which is known in advance, (and stands for "Points To Nothing",) so you can later safely do `if( pointer == NULL ) { pointer = someMeaningfulValue; }`.